# Passing Node variables from Jade to included html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to access jade vars from an included html file in jade. For example...

Route:

```
router.get('/htmltest', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('htmltest', { title: 'HTML TEST' });
});
```

Jade:

```
block content
    include htmltest.html
```

htmltest.html:

```
<p>This is included html #{title}</p>
```

The title doesn't display in html. I guess I have a scoping issue. Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every line in jade that starts with an open bracket `<` is considered a single string of text. You need to change the htmltest.html file to...

```
p This is included html #{title}
```